# Oracle INSTR fun with 4 parameter in Java Program?

Tags: java, java-stored-procedures

In Oracle :

Case 1:

```
SELECT INSTR('Viveok Srinivoasamoorthy','o',15,1) FROM DUAL;
```

Output: 19

Case 2:
     SELECT INSTR('Viveok Srinivoasamoorthy','o',15,2) FROM DUAL;
Output: 20

same like, I need to develop a java program with 4 parameter(string, substring, start_position and nthoccurrence)  to achieve.

This is the code I tried , but in the below code I can't able to find the nth occurance:

```
public static int nthoccur(String str1,String str2,int occurs )
{
    int f_occurance=0;
    f_occurance=str1.indexOf(str2, occurs-1)+1;
    System.out.println("f_occurance Value------*** "+f_occurance);
    return f_occurance;     
} 

public static void main(String args[])
{

int resultinst=nthoccur("Viveok Srinivoasamoorthy","o",15);
System.out.println(resultinst);
}
```

Output:

```
f_occurance Value------*** 19
19
```

Now I want to find the 2nd occurrence "o" from 15th position of string using java program. How can I achive the Case 2 using Java program?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a "other people write code for you" service. Please post the code that you have written so far; and tell us where you are stuck. "Stuck at step 0; please help getting started" isn't accepted here.

Comment: Never add more information via comments. Edit your question instead. And please: turn to the help center first, and spend some time there to understand how "good questions" do look like. Good questions get good answers; bad questions ... not so much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that should mimic [INSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm) .

Comments will help you understand how it works, step by step :

```
public static int instr(final String str, final String substring, int position, final int occurrence) {

    // matches counter
    int count = 0;
    // index of last match
    int indexFound = 0;

    // while we haven't reached the desired match count, and we still find another match
    while (count != occurrence && (indexFound = str.indexOf(substring, position)) != -1)

    {
        // increment match count
        count++;
        // position the next search index, to the end of the current match
        position = indexFound + substring.length();

    }

    if (count == occurrence) {
        // the number of occurrences was matched, return the last match index
        return indexFound + 1; // index in Java starts at 0
    } else {
        // the number of occurrences was not matched, return 0
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you so much @Berger its worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

here is one more way : -1 means no occurence.

`getInstring(String input, String substr, int start, int occurence) {
char[] tempstring = input.substring(start).replaceAll(substr, "-").toCharArray();
        int occurindex = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tempstring.length; i++) {
            if (":-".equals(":" + tempstring[i])) {
                occurindex++;
                counter = i;
            }
            if (occurindex == occurence) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return counter == 0 ? -1 : counter + start + 1;
    }`